# cakephp default.ctp which controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a site developed in cakephp 2 and I want that into my default.ctp there is a menu with some elements taked from the database.
How can I change the elements which controller I have to use? Where I have to put my query? Because if I was into a model is easy but into the default.ctp? How can I do that?
Here is my default.ctp:

```
<body>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>


                    <?php
                        if (!empty($authUser)) {
                        ?>
                        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('I want to change this',   array('controller' => 'ingredients',    'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('I want to change this',       array('controller' => 'brands',         'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('I want to change this',   array('controller' => 'manufacturers',  'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
                    <?php
                            // $is_logged from UsersController->beforeFilter
                            echo $this->element ('header_menu_logged');
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Competizioni',        array('controller' => 'brands',         'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Cerca',   array('controller' => 'manufacturers',  'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
                            <?php
                            // $current_model
                            echo $this->element ('header_menu', array('selected' => 'Pippo'));
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
                <?php
                // messaggi di stato per le azioni

                if (empty($flash_element)) {
                    $flash_element = $this->Session->read('flash_element');
                    if (empty($flash_element)) {
                        $flash_element = 'default';
                    }
                }

                // echo '>'.$flash_element.'<';

                $auth_msg = $this->Session->flash('auth', array ('element' => 'flash_'.$flash_element));
                $flash_msg = $this->Session->flash('flash', array ('element' => 'flash_'.$flash_element));

                if (!empty($auth_msg)) {
                    echo $auth_msg;
                }

                if (!empty($flash_msg)) {
                    echo $flash_msg;
                }
                ?>

                <section><!--class="contents"-->
                <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I suggest doing `$this->set('anyString', $varStringOfTheLink);` in your `beforeRender()` or `beforeFilter()` in appController.php .

Do your query from there and then use the `set()` function to set a variable for your view.

Then in default.ctp you will be able to use `$anyString`.

So to do a quick wrap-up. Do the query in your appController, before filter or before render, then set it so your view can use it. The first parameter of the `set()` function is the name of the var you want to use in your view. Just put a `$` before. The second paremeter is the value of the variable you want.

```
//appController.php
function beforeFilter(){
    $myQueryVar = $this->Model->find('whateverIWant');
    $this->set('myLinkOne', $myQueryVar);
}

//layouts/default.ctp
echo $this->Html->link($myLinkOne,   array('controller' => 'ingredients',    'action' => 'index'));
```